# ActiveAdmin select all batch action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Hey guys I want to perform batch actions in active admin and I have set the following to true

```
config.batch_actions = true
```

in active_admin.rb

Also added selectable_column under the Model's active admin generated file in the index block.

When I click on the top most check box to select all, nothing happens. It just checks that one checkbox. Please let me know of a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the latest version of ActiveAdmin from github. This [issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2027) has been fixed, but there is no released version yet.

`gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'`

Comment: I am still facing this issue in active admin 0.6